# `dapp-build: building with linked libraries` | why do I get this?

Tags: decentralized-applications, dapptools

I have a dapptools project, and when I run `dapp test` I get the following before my tests happen:

```
dapp-build: building with linked libraries
dapp: Predeploying test library lib/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/utils/Address.sol:Address at 0x1F39490BdD8e57Ed3CA877783E563cC0B329431b
dapp: Predeploying test library lib/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/utils/Strings.sol:Strings at 0x7496c5C5c86FB8cE60221e5BeFf3b7806CFd09a7
```

However, I have another project where this doesn't happen. This seems to take a lot of time.

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `.dapprc` if you don't have one already, and add:

```
export DAPP_LINK_TEST_LIBRARIES=0
```

This will skip compiling all the files in the `lib` folder, which we don't need to do.